# How to get off of Lighting Stance?

Tags: blade-and-soul

As a Blade Master, after using Lighting Draw or the skill that teleports you behind the enemy, you enter into the Lighting Stance.

The problem is: other than waiting some time without attacking or running out of focus, I don't know how to get back to the basic stance.

Comment: If you look in your martial tome, some moves will say what stance they put you in after (or atleast it used to). Try looking in there

Answer (score 1):

Although **Block** is a basic stance move, it can also be used during the *Draw Stance*, and doing so will force you out of the stance.

Other means, for sake of being exhaustive:

- Use **Cyclone** after resisting an attack with appropriately specialized **Pentaslash**.
- There is a specialization of **Honed Slash** which forces you out of the *Draw Stance*.
- Use **Blindside** counterclockwise (default key: E). On a side note, counterclockwise **Blindside** during the *Draw Stance* does not trigger the cooldown of it.